# Replace string using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I always encounter regular expressions but I don't really try to understand and use them. But my current project is forcing me to use a regular expression so I need someone who can give me the correct regex to replace a simple string. Basically I'm replacing a small subset of longtext retrieved from a database. The longtext is just a paragraph(s) with text anchors in a form of:

```
<a href="example.com" title="blah3x">Example</a>
```

So the question is how do I replace the value of the title attribute? Please note that the text may contain two more anchor tags so I'd like to able to specifically target each of them.

**EDIT:**
I'd like to use pure PHP on this. I think I know how to do this using js/jquery.

Comment: @Barmar: I didn't build the project. I know it's really bad designed which is basically the reason I want to use regex..

Comment: See John Conde's answer, you can use functions specifically for parsing HTML rather than a regexp. It has nothing to do with the design of the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<a href="example.com" title="blah3x">Example</a>');
$anchors = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($anchors as $anchor)
{
    $anchor->setAttribute('target', '__blank');
}
$html = $doc->saveHTML();

echo $html;
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VId6Uo)

Comment: While this is certainly the preferred method in most cases, I don't think it's right to call it the `correct way`. For example:  if I had to parse 10 billion pages I would opt to use `regex` or more likely even `strpos`.

Comment: See question `my current project is forcing me to use a regular expression so I need someone who can give me the correct regex to replace a simple string.`

Comment: I think this might work. However, I can't access anchor objects without iterating. Why can't I use `$anchors[0]->setAttribute()`?

Answer (score 4):

## Description

You could do this with the following regex

`(<a\b[^>]*?\btitle=(['"]))(.*?)\2`

[image]

## Summary

- `(` start capture group 1
- `<a\b` consume open angle bracket and an `a` followed by a word break
- `[^>]*?` consume all non close angle bracket characters up to... this forces the regex to stay inside the anchor tag
- `\btitle=` consume a word break and `title=`, the break helps do some additional checking
- `(['"])` capture group 2, ensure the an open single or double quote is being used
- `)` close capture group 1
- `(.*?)` start capture group 3, and non greedy consume to collect all text inside the quotes
- `\2` reference back to the string from capture group 2, if you used a single quote to open the value, then a single quote will be required to close the value. Same if you had use a double quote.

In the replace command I'm simply replacing the entire found string from `<a to the close quote` with: group capture 1, followed by the desired text `NewValue` followed by the close quote from group capture 2.

## PHP example

```
<?php
$sourcestring="<a href="example.com" title="blah3x">Example</a>";
echo preg_replace('/(<a\b[^>]*?\btitle=([\'"]))(.*?)\2/im','\1NewValue\2',$sourcestring);
?>

$sourcestring after replacement:
<a href="example.com" title="NewValue">Example</a>
```

## Disclaimer

Since parsing text via a html parser is **not the desired solution**, I'll skip the usual soap box disclaimer about parsing html with Regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string=preg_replace(
'@<a (.*)title="(.*)"([^>]*)>(.*)</a>@iU',
'<a $1title="'.$replacement.'"$3>$4</a>',
$string);
```

Note that the `i` at the end of the expression makes it case insensitive, and the `U` makes it ungreedy.